# How to resolve the error: java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/core/Promise

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, vert.x

i have created a maven project where i wrote code for kafka consumer to retrieve the messages from kafka server. i am using vertx framework with vertx-kafka-client dependency. According to vertx kafka docs (*https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-kafka-client/java/#_using_the_vert_x_kafka_client*),
i have setup the code and while running the program i am getting error as **java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/core/Promise**

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this error is

- Right-click on your project
- Go to **Maven** -> **Update Project**
- After update, Run the program

when we import projects to IDE, sometimes we forget to update the project and directly running it will cause the error.